# К вопросу о свойствах русского языка (5)

Tags: орфография, троллинг

Предположим, я внесу предложение, чтобы русские писали цветовые оттенки (ярко-красный, бледно-жёлтый, светло-серый, тёмно-фиолетовый, ...) без небуквенного орфографического знака "-" (дефис), который не отличается от знака переноса "-".

**Вопрос:** Противоречит ли указанное предложение хотя бы одному свойству русского языка?

P.S.

По меньшей мере один русский не только называет подснежником белоснежным  растение Galanthus nivalis L., но и пишет слово "белоснежный" без небуквенного орфографического знака "-".

Comment: Белоснежный - это цвета белого снега, а не белый и снежный, так что постскриптум тут не к месту.

Comment: 1. Спасибо за замечание.

2. Я не возражаю, чтобы слово "черноснежный" было равнозначно словосочетанию "цвета чёрного снега".

Comment: Не возражаю, чтобы @Галактион засорял форум однотипными скучными вопросами. В конце концов, я же не модератор.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте посмотрим примеры из Нацкорпуса?

> Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк. Три конца (1890)  В одном месте Тишка соскочил с козел и сорвал **большой бледножелтый цветок** с пушистою мохнатою ножкой.
>
> Л.В. Никулин. Памяти Есенина (1957)  **Светлосерый пиджак** облегал его стройную фигуру и очень шел ему ― такое умение с изящной небрежностью носить городской костюм я видел еще у одного человека, вышедшего из народных низов, ― у Шаляпина.
>
> И. А. Ефремов. Час быка (1968-1969)  Трое путешественников и три верные девятиножки упорно преодолевали подъем, углубляясь в тень **темнофиолетовых обрывов** главного массива.
>
> М. А. Шолохов. Поднятая целина. Книга 1 (1958) В кругу, распустив крылья, ходят два кочета, **один ― яркокрасный,** другой ― оперенный иссиня-черным, ― грачиным пером.

Раньше все русские классики писали названия "сложных" цветов без дефиса, потом некие умники ввели для них дефис. Почему богиня -*крутобедрая и высокогрудая*,  а соски у нее - *темно-розовые*?))) Что за двойные филологические стандарты. Хотя писатели и посейчас шарахаются от дефисов в подобных случаях :

> Борис Хазанов. Праматерь (2002) Ее пальцы развязывали что-то там, развели в стороны, я увидел ее **темнорозовые соски**, обведенные кружками...

Можно ввести двойную норму, если на то пошло. Кому как нравится. Я - за классическое *бездефисие* с соединительной **о**. "*Аромат малосольных бледнозеленых огурцов наполнил комнату*"

> А. А. Фадеев. Молодая гвардия (1943-1951) А у Ули **глаза были большие, темнокарие**, ― не глаза, а очи, с длинными ресницами, молочными белками, черными таинственными зрачками, из самой, казалось, глубины которых снова струился этот влажный сильный свет.

Comment: 1. Большое спасибо.

2. Вы вправе дополнить Ваш ответ предложением: "По моему мнению, обсуждаемое предложение Галактиона не противоречит ни одну свойству русского языка."

Answer (score 2):

Противоречит. У русского языка есть такое свойство - *выражать мысли*. Или ещё *обозначать понятия*. Для выражения (обозначения) нужны *средства*.

У русского языка средства очень точно соответствуют задачам выражения, обозначения (это тоже такое свойство р.я. - точность). Если какое-то средство убрать, выражения перестанут быть точными, и русский язык перестанет быть русским языком (соль перестанет быть солёной).

Не убирайте из русского письма дефис! (собираю подписи в защиту дефиса:-)

Comment: Я не возражаю, чтобы сборщики подписи в защиту дефиса исполняли перед сном: "... Кипит наш разум возмущённый и в смертный бой вести готов..."

Answer (score 0):

Подписуюсь за дефис.

С дефисом получается два самостоятельных слова, каждое из которых может нести ударение.
Такие слова удобны для проверки компьютерными программами.
На все авторские выверты словарных статей не напасёшься!  ;)

Comment: Я предпочту авторские выверты :

 *В узких вазах томленье умирающих лилий.

 **Запад был меднокрасный**. Вечер был голубой.

 О Леконте де Лиле[1] мы с тобой говорили,

 О холодном поэте мы грустили с тобой.

 Мы не раз открывали шелковистые томы

 И читали спокойно и шептали: не тот!

 Но тогда нам сверкнули все слова, все истомы,

 Как кочевницы звёзды, что восходят раз в год.

 Так певучи и странны, в наших душах воскресли

 Рифмы древнего солнца, мир нежданно-большой,

 И сквозь сумрак вечерний запрокинутый в кресле

 Резкий профиль креола с лебединой душой*

Comment: Предпочтения - одно, а логика - другое...  

Недавно мне встретился стих на 60 строк полностью без знаков препинания - только 3 восклицательных знака в конце. Автор посчитал всякие там точки да запятые излишними - он-де пишет Душой, и надеется, что родственные Души и так поймут.  

С формальной точки зрения каждое бездефисное словосочетание заслуживает отдельной точки в словаре. Это получатся целые страницы, заполненные возможными сочетаниями цветов. А поскольку для поэтов "возможные" - понятие очень растяжимое...

Comment: И когда это писал Гумилёв?  
Конечно, с запятыми он не обращался, как в примере выше, но слово "томы" сейчас уже ненормативно, после "кочевницы" я бы поставил дефис...  
Ну, записал Поэт 2-стопный анапест в 4 стопы... Так не рекомендовать же всем поступать так и именно так!  
Вольный творческий полёт и нормативы правописания находятся в несколько разных плоскостях.